# Check if value is null in array in object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

Here is the `$object` that Microsoft is returning to me:

```
object(Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event)#56 (1) {
  ["_propDict":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["@odata.context"]=>
    string(245) "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('email%40outlook.com')/calendars('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')/calendarView"
    ["value"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to check if `value`'s array contains nothing in it. I'm having trouble accessing "value" as it just says array. Here is what I've already tried doing:

`$object->array;`

`$object->array();`

`$object[0];`

```
foreach ($object as $key) {
    var_dump($key);
}
```

None of those work.

---

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if(empty($object->array['value'])) {
    echo 'value is empty';
}
```

Comment: `_propDict` is protected.  Which means short of reflection, it's not accessible outside of the class.

Comment: You won't be able to access a protected object property directly - does the class offer any getter methods?

Comment: Thank you guys. So the problem is that Microsoft does provide a way to get those protected properties, for example, `$object->getSubject()`, **BUT** `$object->getValue()` is not valid. Thanks everyone though!

Answer (score 0):

[`Entity.getProperties()` function](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/src/Model/Entity.php#L52) could be utilized for that purpose which returns *the list of properties*.  `Entity` is a *base* class for `Event` entity.

The following example demonstrates how to determine whether entity contains property using [`array_key_exists` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
$requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$targetDriveId";
$drive = $this->client->createRequest("GET", $requestUrl)
     ->setReturnType(Model\Drive::class)
     ->execute();

$properties = $drive->getProperties();  //get all properties
if (array_key_exists('id', $properties)) { //verify for id property
    print $properties["id"];
}
```